# Vue-Router + webpack + lazy loading with syntax-dynamic-import doesn't work

Tags: webpack, vue-router

Could you please help me figure out on what am I doing wrong. If I use the following syntax  for importing

```
const Home = (resolve) => import('./views/Home.vue').then(resolve)
```

I receive the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)
```

If I use standard Import from './views/Home.vue' I receive no errors and everything works as expected.

I have added  `syntax-dynamic-import` plugin into .babelrc

Here is my webpack-config just in case:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const sassOpt = {
    sourceMap: true,
    includePaths: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor/zurb/foundation/scss'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/motion-ui/src'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/sass')]
}
// noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            'webpack/hot/dev-server',
            // ?reload=true enables full page reload on hmr failure
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
            './app'
        ]
    },
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
        filename: '[name].chunk.js',
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].[id].js',
        publicPath: '/js/',
        pathinfo: true
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015'],
                    plugins: ['lodash']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    esModule: true,
                    loaders: {
                        scss: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?' + JSON.stringify(sassOpt), // <style lang="scss">
                        sass: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax' // <style lang="sass">
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: sassOpt
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                context: '/'
            }
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Syntax from here does not work as well

https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the context of your question correctly: you need to let `vue-router` worry about resolving the promise.  If you're playing ball with `vue webpack` I'm not sure why the vue-router doc example wouldn't work.

In your example above, it looks like you're trying to resolve the promise early.  remember that the execution context of the promise occurs *inside* the `then` callback.  [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) suggest that:

```
const Foo = () => import('./Foo.vue')
```

will be resolved when the '/foo' path is hit:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
  ]
})
```

As an extra step, since we're working dynamically here, why bother writing a huge list of dynamic imports and painstakingly assigning them to the router one-at-a-time? we can create something pretty readable and easy to maintain by decoupling our dynamic route imports into a separate file*

assuming you're working off the boilerplate provided with `vue webpack init`, Create a `routes.js` file adjacent to '@/router/index.js' similar to the below:

```
export const MainMenu = {
 'Foo': () => import('@/components/Foo.vue'),
 'Bar': () => import('@/components/Bar.vue')
}
```

then, in the '@/router/index.js':

```
import _ from 'lodash' // used for brevity in this instance; feel free to use something else.

import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld' // static import index component
import {MainMenu} from './routes'

export default new Router({
  routes: _.concat(
    [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    }],
    Object.keys(MainMenu).map((route) => {
      return {
        name: route,
        path: `/${_.kebabCase(route)}`,
        component: MainMenu[route]
      }
    })
  )
})
```

That's it, all routes in the `MainMenu` export handled for you!

---

*accepting the possible caveat made by @KieranGrosvenor below their post about issues with chunks; I have yet to encounter that problem, but it's something to be aware of.